# Rails - Enabling Nginx with https inside a Docker container using Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx, docker

I'm having trouble enabling https in my application. I managed to make it work without ssl, but after trying out other tutorials, none seem to have worked for me. I'll try keep the code short and share the most important parts.

Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/passenger-customizable

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    dialog \
    net-tools \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
    nginx nginx-extras\
    rsync \
    bzip2 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD config/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
ADD config/nginx/fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem
ADD config/nginx/privkey.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem
ADD config/nginx/rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf
ADD config/nginx/postgres-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/postgres-env.conf
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web-production: &web-production
  <<: *web
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  expose:
    - '80'
    - '443'
  command: passenger start -p 443 -b '0.0.0.0'
  environment:
    RACK_ENV: production
    RAILS_ENV: production
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;

  passenger_app_env production;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3;

  ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem";
  ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only_environments => ['production', /^QA/]
```

I generated my certificates using certbot.

My current stack:

- Docker/Compose
- Rails 4.2
- Ruby 2.3
- Nginx

Comment: I would extract nginx from the same image as your rails server, create a new service in your docker-compose file to boot nginx, and let it forward each request to your ruby container, have a look into https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy it's a very powerful image to manage that